# Creating new vector layers / save output in QGIS scripting?

Tags: pyqgis

I need to create a script in QGIS which stores outputs. In this case, official documentation didn't help to me.

When I use geoprocessing (processing.runalg()) for vector layers. In some cases, output is selection of the input vector (eg. select by location) and in other cases, output is a vector layers (eg. split by lines with lines).

How do I save both types of outputs as:

1. new memory layer;
2. new shapefile saved on disk?

Comment: Could you post your current script to allow potential answerers to help please? :)

Comment: When I try to create new layer from extracting by attribute: `processing.runalg("qgis:extractbyattribute",landuse,"Landuse",0,3,riverbed)` where `riverbed` is the output argument and I don't know, how to properly use it, when I want to create new memory/shapefile layer from it.

Comment: I'm not too experienced in this but perhaps try: `processing.runalg("qgis:extractbyattribute",landuse,"Landuse",0,3,"memory:riverbed")` or even `processing.runandload("qgis:extractbyattribute",landuse,"Landuse",0,3,"memory:riverbed")`

Comment: It returns this error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range`